# Can't delete objects with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined myself an api for use with Angular.js:

```
angular.module('api', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Server', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/api/servers/:name');
    })
    .factory('ActiveServer', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/api/servers/active/:name', {},
            { start: {method: 'POST'}, stop: {method: 'DELETE'} });
    });
```

The idea, is that I have a set of defined servers, available through the `/api/servers/` uri. A particular server can be started by adding it to the `/api/servers/active/` uri, and stopped by deleting it.

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
$scope.start = function() {
    ActiveServer.start(this.server);
};

$scope.stop = function() {
    ActiveServer.stop(this.server);
};
```

which again is triggered by buttons

```
    <div class="well span4" ng-repeat="server in servers">
        <h1>{{server.definition.name}}</h1>
        <span class="label label-info">{{server.status}}</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="start()">Start</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
    </div>
```

Starting the server works alright, but I have trouble stopping it. The code above ends up with the following request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/servers/active?$$hashKey=005&_events=[object+Object]&definition=[object+Object]&status=ready
Request Method:DELETE
```

The `definition`-part of my server object, containing the name that identifies the server to stop, isn´t serialized right.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your API (`ActiveServer`) only needs to receive the server's name to work, then pass only the server's name during the service call. Like this:

```
$scope.start = function() {
    ActiveServer.start({name: this.server.definition.name});
};

$scope.stop = function() {
    ActiveServer.stop({name: this.server.definition.name});
};
```

Passing the entire `this.server` object in any service call will result on the entire object being parametrized into the HTTP request.

**extended explanation:**

When you use something like `api/servers/:name` on your `$resource` URL, you are basically saying that the `:name` part will be replaced by the value of a property **with the same name** (in this case, 'name') received on the parameters (i.e. `{name: 'someName'}`).

From the angularJS [$resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template
>   if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search
>   query after the ?. Given a template /path/:verb and parameter
>   {verb:'greet', salutation:'Hello'} results in URL
>   /path/greet?salutation=Hello. If the parameter value is prefixed with
>   @ then the value of that parameter is extracted from the data object
>   (useful for non-GET operations).

So, if you call `service.get({name: 'abc'})` then URL of the request will be 
`api/server/abc`

If you call `service.get({name: 'abc', id: '123'})` then URL will be `api/server/abc?id=123`

In your case, the `this.server` Object looks something like this:

```
{ 
  $$hashKey: 005,
  _events: {},
  definition: {},
  status: ready
}
```

Since AngularJS does **not do in-depth parametrization**, `_events` and `definitions` are shown as `_events=[object+Object]&definition=[object+Object]` on the URL.

Comment: That may be an workaround - I'll have to try it out - but I would love an explanation on why my solution doesn't work, and how this is supposed to be used.

Comment: Updated my answer with some extended explanations. Hope it helps.